# Pantalla negra al abrir la aplicación en Android. Juego de Unity

Tags: android, unity, unity2d

En modo editor, en la simulación, funciona perfectamente, pero cuando descargo la aplicación de la playstore, en la versión tester, es solo una pantalla negra.

[image: Canvas and maincamera configuration]

Comment: Si descargas desde la playstore aunque sea como "tester", se supone que no deberías poder abrir el proyecto como aplicación.

Comment: Y como funciona entonces? :o